# リストを作るときに、必要な要素数になるまで回したい

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

データセットを作成したい。そこで以下のコードに改良を加えたい。
コードで計算されているDisが、1<Dis<2の間に収まるようにしたい。
つまり、それ以外の値を取るDisの行の組み合わせは捨てたいです。

しかし、最終的に得られるP_sample_2のデータは10×6の行列になるようにしたい。
どのように考えるのがよいでしょうか？

```
P_sample = []
PP_sample = []
Dis_sample = []
for _ in range(10):
# P_sample_allからランダムに行を取り出すための乱数を作成
    PP = np.random.choice(P_sample_all.shape[0], 2, replace=False)
    PP_sample.append(PP)
    
# 取り出した原子位置間の距離を計算
    Dis=np.sqrt((P_sample_all[PP[0],0]-P_sample_all[PP[1],0])**2+
              (P_sample_all[PP[0],1]-P_sample_all[PP[1],1])**2+
              (P_sample_all[PP[0],2]-P_sample_all[PP[1],2])**2)
    Dis_sample.append(Dis)
    
# 取り出した行を1つの行として扱うために変形
    P_sample_1 = P_sample_all[PP, :]
    P_sample.append(P_sample_1)
P_sample_2 = np.reshape(P_sample, (10, 6))
PP_sample, Dis_sample, P_sample_2
```

Comment: 見やすいようにコード全体をマークダウンで記入してください。

> comtinueを使い飛ばすことはできますが、飛ばした回数をもう一度処理できません。
どのように考えるのがよいでしょうか？
上記処理は質問のコード中に見当たりませんのでその状況が分かりません。

Comment: Dis以下をif文を用いて場合分けをしようとして、Dis_sample.append以下をcontinueでスキップするようにしようと調べていました。しかし、continueを用いるとスキップされるだけでfor文の工程は1回分カウントされているので、自分の求めてるものではないと断念しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# 取り出した原子位置間の距離を計算
Dis=np.sqrt((P_sample_all[PP[0],0]-P_sample_all[PP[1],0])**2+
          (P_sample_all[PP[0],1]-P_sample_all[PP[1],1])**2+
          (P_sample_all[PP[0],2]-P_sample_all[PP[1],2])**2)
Dis_sample.append(Dis)
```

を

```
# 取り出した原子位置間の距離を計算
Dis=np.sqrt((P_sample_all[PP[0],0]-P_sample_all[PP[1],0])**2+
          (P_sample_all[PP[0],1]-P_sample_all[PP[1],1])**2+
          (P_sample_all[PP[0],2]-P_sample_all[PP[1],2])**2)
# 1<Dis<2　という条件が満たされる場合に、DisをDis_sampleに追加する。
If((1<Dis) and (Dis<2)):
    Dis_sample.append(Dis)
```

というように、条件を満たすもののみをリストに登録するようにして、リストの長さが必要な要素数に達したらループを終了させたらよ

Answer (score 0):

単純には二重ループを書いてはいかがでしょうか。

```
for _ in range(10):
    accepted = False
    while not accepted:
        x = generate()
        accepted = condition(x)
    sample.append(x)
```